# how to see git log automatic refresh

Tags: bash, git, bash-scripting

I'm trying to create a script that would should me the `git log` and refresh every 1 second. This is what I have:

```
while :
do
clear
git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
sleep 1
done
```

It's not working because `git log` waits for the user to hit `q` to quit - and therefor the loop is stuck. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34587331/1557472) from SO, you can stop the need to quit by adding `--no-pager` immediately after the `git`.

It's not the `log` command that is waiting for `q`, it's the `less` tool that is doing the pagination. By telling `git` that you don't want the pager, the `log` command will print all output and then quit immediately.

Of course if there is more than one screen worth, you'll get everything printed out and would have to scroll up to see the most recent commits. You can combat this by limiting the number of commits to log by adding something like `-22`. That would limit to 22 commits, you could of course pick a different number.

Something like:

```
while :
do
clear
git --no-pager log --all --decorate --oneline -22 --graph
sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 9):

You can make that a one-liner with `watch`:

```
watch --color -n 3 git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph --color=always
```

Tweak the `-n` flag to change the refresh rate.